# Streaming Audio [from Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, audio-streaming

I have a Python app I have been working on which generates music in real time from composers scores. It works by mixing samples according to rules written by the composer, introducing elements of randomness.

Crucially, it all happens in real time. No WAV/OGG/MP3 files are produced.

During development I have been using PyGame and PyDub to create the music, mixing together 24 channels of audio samples into a single output. The output during development has been played via Pygame Mixer straight to the default audio device, so I listened to the music on headphoens as I developed.

Now, however, I want to put all of this into an online app and serve the audio over the web. When a user lands on the home page I want them to hear the music streamed down to their machine.

The question is: how best to do it?

During development I assumed that at the last minute I could replace my audio device with something that took the audio stream fed to it and redirected it to a port or similar so that I could have a player embedded in the home page pointing at that port and playing the audio coming from it.

Howewveer, now that I've got to that point it is beginning to dawn on me that I have never really understood how audio works when it is served up that way.

As mentioned earlier, ther is no posibility of exporting a file and then pointing a player at the URL - the music is potentially endless.

Any clues? I've searched extensively via Google but all I get are, eg., pieces about using an 'audio server' to deliver mp3 files. I'm Feel I just misunderstand soem basic concepts here and am not asking the right questions.

In my dreams I simply add something like this to my code:

1. install snappy_library.py that creates a virtual audio driver.
2. tell snappy_library to redirect any audio sent its way to PORT nnnn
3. tell Pygame to use snappy_library as its audio device.
4. retire

Thanks in advance for any pointers / context setting / examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995677/audio-streaming-by-websockets might have some useful info